# Save output image in matlab window to image

Tags: image, matlab, matlab-figure

I have a image and some contours as bellow figure. I want to save the output into image (png or jpg). The saved image only contains the image region without the matlab window. Let see my example in the figure. Could you have me implement it by matlab? This is my code to make output figure

```
img = imread('coins.png');
mask_red=zeros(size(img));
mask_green=zeros(size(img));
mask_red(30:160,40:170)=1;
mask_green(70:100,60:130)=1;
imagesc(uint8(img),[0 255]),colormap(gray),axis off;axis equal,
hold on;
[c1,h1] = contour(mask_red,[0 0],'r','Linewidth',3);
[c2,h2] = contour(mask_green,[0 0],'g','Linewidth',3);
hold off;
%% Save output figure
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want the result on the left or the right? Try `print` and check its documentation.

Comment: I want to result in right side. The left side is output figure that made by above code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `getframe` and `cdata` idiom.  If the figure is open, simply do this:

```
f = getframe;
im = f.cdata;
```

`im` will contain the image that was contained inside your frame as a RGB image.  Running your code in your post, then the above code, then doing `imshow(im)`, we get:

[image]

If you want to save the image, just use [`imwrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html):

```
imwrite(im, 'coins_final.png');
```

The image will be saved in a file called `coins_final.png`.

Comment: How about the save the above image into the image file? imwrite can be one option, right?

Comment: @john2182 - If you want to save it, use `imwrite`. I'll update my post.

Comment: @john2182 - Updated.  Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: @john2182 - No problem at all.  Good luck!

Comment: I found that it will cut a rectangular region and save it into image. If the image is not square. So the cutting image maintains some unwanted region (let see your figure in left and right edges). Is it possible to remote them to make clear output image?

Comment: @john2182 - Unfortunately this is the only way I know of to get an image from the figure.  You may need to simply crop out the columns that are unwanted.... so try doing this: `im2 = im(:,10:end-10,:);`, then do `imwrite(im2, 'coins_final.png');`.